# Loop Bounds vs. Iteration Domain in Polyhedral optimization

Tags: optimization

**Context:**

I was reading a tutorial on [polyhedral optimization](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/553703704). But got confused **while trying to translate the iteration domain (i.e. loop bound) to set builder notation.**

**Problem Description:**

*A code snippet from the article*;

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2*N; ++i)
    S: Z[i] = 0.;
```

The iteration domain for the statement 'S' is described with the set-builder notation as

`{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ N}`. But the code says that i should go up to or equal to `2*N`.

**Example Case:**

Let’s consider the code given above. And also assume N = 5

Then this loop will iterate from `i = 0 to 10 (where, 2xN = 2x5 = 10)`.

But from the set builder notation, we can see that the iteration domain should be in the range of

`0 <= i <= N, i.e, 0 <= i <= 5`.

But considering the real code snippet,

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2*N; ++i)
    S: Z[i] = 0;
```

`i` go up to 10.

**So my doubts are…**

1. Then should I write the set builder as `{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ 2N}`  or `{S[i] : 0 ≤ i ≤ N}`?
2. For now, even if both of them are correct; later are there any implications/issues that would arise? That I should be concerned on now? I am asking, because I have seen, that those notations are heavily used in forming systems of equations (To solve what, I don’t know yet )

Screenshots are attached from the tutorial for quick review.
Thank you.

[image: Shot1]
[image: Shot2]

Comment: Have you considered that the document you're reading might simply have a mistake in it?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for the response. That's what I am thinking. When I read about iteration domain from other resources I could see there is some issue in this document.